# Image rendering via controller API sometimes breaks when being access by multiple users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, image-rendering

I have here an image rendering method on my api that is being access via url by users in order to display images as source. I don't have a problem when testing locally since I'm only making single user requests. But by the time I deployed it, staging/production testers comes in. The image being rendered is broken because of an internal server error, I'm guessing it is because of the multiple request.

Here's how I do it:

```
[Route("userprofileimage")]
public class UserProfileImageController : Controller
{
    [Route("render")]
    public FileResult Render(string di, string tk, string fi)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(di) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tk) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fi))
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserProfileImages"), fi));

            var isValid = new UserTokenService().ValidateUserToken(Guid.Parse(di), tk);
            if(isValid)
            {
                if (ImageFileNotAvailable(filePath))
                    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserProfileImages"), "default.png"), FileMode.Open), "image/png");
                else
                    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open), "image/png");
            }

        }

        return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserProfileImages"), "default.png"), FileMode.Open), "image/png");
    }

    private bool ImageFileNotAvailable(string fullFilePath)
    {
        return !System.IO.File.Exists(fullFilePath);
    }
}
```

As you can see there are token and id checks before the actual rendering of the image.

I have no specific reason on my approach on this one. I just find it convenient to have links as image sources.

I was expecting that the requests from multiple users will wait until a previous execution is done before going in but I guess they go in simultaneously. So at some point the file is currently open or being manipulated and another request comes in. Hence the error.

Any ideas on how can I improve this?

Comment: Where do you think you may have multiple threads accessing the same file? Why do you have a nested Path.Combine where the outer call has an empty second arg?

Comment: I'm actually not sure of the behavior of the threads on this one but I'm sure that there are multiple request on render method by different users. Does it create different threads per request? Sorry for a dumb question. The nested Path.Combine will be optimized, I haven't had the chance yet to improve the code. But I surely will improve it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The only hard coded filename I see is default.png which I think is only read. If you need a temp file to write to, use the OS tempfile functions. And, yes, the server will create a thread for each request so that's why they appear simultaeously to your method

Comment: My bad on this one I actually found out that the error is caused by the generated link being wrong. Thank you for your time and help. I'll gladly give you an upvote for pointing out the nested Path.Combine.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear you fixed it.